# On Iframe embed click show a div or counter start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I am trying to show or start count when I click on a youtube embed Iframe .
Here is my code

```
    <iframe id="startcount" width="900" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qAM8wEHPccU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <span align="center" style="color:#0091bf; font-weight:bold; font-size:24px;">You will be redirected in 
    <span id="counter">30</span> second(s) for credit verification. </span>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#startcount").click(function() {

                function countdown() {
                var i = document.getElementById('counter');
                if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
                //location.href = 'earn_credit_ac.php?ads_id=<?php echo $del_id; ?>';
                }
                i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
                }
                setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);

                });
    });


    </script>
```

1. Click on youtube embeded video iframe
2. start counting

help me I am new in jquery .

Thanks to All

Answer (score 0):

If you are counting down then you should check if the value is greater than 0, not less than 0.
The following code should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#startcount").click(function() {
        function countdown() {
          var i = $("#counter");
          var value = parseInt(i.html());
          var interval;

          if (value >= 0) { // I think you want "greater equal" (>=) instead of "less equal" (<=)
            //location.href = 'earn_credit_ac.php?ads_id=<?php echo $del_id; ?>';
          }
          else {
              clearInterval(interval); // stop interval if counted to -1
          }

          i.html(value - 1);
        }

        setInterval(countdown, 1000);
      });
    });
```

Comment: no its now work for me :( when I click on youtube ifrmae than the counting start thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using another method to complete this task.

Html :

```
  <button id="play-button" class="btn mobile-full" style="padding:10px;"> Play </button>

  <iframe id="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/NV16WtEXP6E?autohide=2&border=0&wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&controls=0&showinfo=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <div align="center">
  <span align="center" style="color:#0091bf; font-weight:bold; font-size:24px;">You will be redirected in 
 <span id="counter"><?php echo $vid_duration; ?></span> second(s) for credit verification. </span>
 </div>
```

Css :

```
.button {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    fill: white; 
  }
}

.defs {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

iframe {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.buttons {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #f06d06;
  float: left;
}
```

JavaScript :

```
<script>

// https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

// global variable for the player
var player;

// this function gets called when API is ready to use
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  // create the global player from the specific iframe (#video)
  player = new YT.Player('video', {
    events: {
      // call this function when player is ready to use
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {

  // bind events
  var playButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
  playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.playVideo();

    function countdown() {
        var i = document.getElementById('counter');
        if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
            location.href = 'earn_credit_ac.php?ads_id=<?php echo $del_id; ?>';
        }
        i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
    }
    setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);

  });



}

// Inject YouTube API script
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


</script>
```

This is the only way to play youtube video on mobile and same time start the time counter .

Thanks to all .